# How can i remove http://webservices.rki.dk this in xml

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-namespaces

I want to remove namespace in xml.Can you please write regular expression in javascript for the following two strings.I want these two strings in my whole xml.

```
xmlns="http://webservices.rki.dk"  
xmlns="http://webservices.rki.dk/"
```

Comment: You want to remove them completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `string.replace()` to get rid of those. [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

**Example to globally replace in a string (You need to escape some chars to make it work):**

```
var str1 = 'xmlns="http://webservices.rki.dk" hello xmlns="http://webservices.rki.dk"'
var str1Fixed = str1.replace(/xmlns=\"http:\/\/webservices.rki.dk\"/g,"");
alert(str1Fixed);
```

Comment: string.replace() replaces only once but it appears many times therefore i need to replace globally..

Comment: To replace globally you just put your search string in between `//` and then add a `g` on the end for global. There is an example of this on the link I originally posted. ex. `/mySearchString/g`